# How to get stored sql function using drupal db_select?

Tags: drupal

I have created sql function called `get_fan_count`. I need to retrieve the data for particular user. How can I get this using `db_select`. Using `db_query` I can fetch this value. But can't using `db_select()`.

Below code is working
`$query = db_query("select uid, get_fan_count(uid) as fan_cnt from users WHERE name LIKE '%test%'");`

I need help to deal with `db_select`

Answer (score 0):

The [`addExpression()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21select.inc/function/SelectQuery%3A%3AaddExpression/7) method is probably what you're looking for:

```
$query = db_select('users', 'u')
  ->fields('u', array('uid'))
  ->condition('u.name', '%' . db_like($string) . '%', 'LIKE');

$query->addExpression('get_fan_count(uid)', 'fan_cnt');

foreach ($query->execute() as $result) {
  // ...
}
```